# Sidebar structure for a small project

Tags: angular, typescript

I found a sidebar on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-extcef?file=src/app/app.component.ts), I would like to use in my project.

There are 2 files that I don't understand, how I should adapt on my project `app.component.html` and `app.component.ts`.

Where I have to put THE HTML -> `app.component.html`

```
<ng-icon-sidebar>
  <!-- Your content goes here, inside the sidebar's tag. This sample content exists for demonstration purposes. -->
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">mail</i>
        </span>
        Inbox
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">send</i>
        </span>
        Outbox
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">favorite</i>
        </span>
        Favorites
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">archive</i>
        </span>
        Archive
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
        </span>
        Trash
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">report</i>
        </span>
        Spam
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- End of sample content for demonstration purposes. -->
</ng-icon-sidebar>
```

And -> `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ng-icon-sidebar';
}
```

Currently in my project, I have 2 folders `Home` and `Login`. I don't know where/how I should adapt the sidebar for `app.component.html` and `app.component.ts`.

The password is `test1` in my project -> [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zx5ukw?file=src/app/views/home/home.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1

You can simply put the sidebar html code in the `app.component.html` File:

```
    <ng-icon-sidebar>
  <!-- Your content goes here, inside the sidebar's tag. This sample content exists for demonstration purposes. -->
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">mail</i>
        </span>
        Inbox
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">send</i>
        </span>
        Outbox
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">favorite</i>
        </span>
        Favorites
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">archive</i>
        </span>
        Archive
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
        </span>
        Trash
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="icon-container">
          <i class="material-icons">report</i>
        </span>
        Spam
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- End of sample content for demonstration purposes. -->
</ng-icon-sidebar>


<!-- nav -->

<div class="navbar-nav" style="float: right" *ngIf="currentUser">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
</div>

<!-- Top Bar Start -->

<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="top-bar-logo">
    <img
      class="fit-picture"
      src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/42/010i.gif"
      alt="img"
    />
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Top Bar End -->

<!-- main app container -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

## Method 2

Make a new component with `ng generare component <component name>`, simply copy and paste the code from the sidebar project and reference this component in your `app.component.html` like this:

```
<!-- nav -->

<app-[your-component-name]>

<div class="navbar-nav" style="float: right" *ngIf="currentUser">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="logout()">Logout</a>
</div>

<!-- Top Bar Start -->

<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="top-bar-logo">
    <img
      class="fit-picture"
      src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/42/010i.gif"
      alt="img"
    />
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Top Bar End -->

<!-- main app container -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I hope i could help you.

Comment: Maldek, I would like to use the second method. In the folder -> `shared` I created `sidebar`, inside, I created `sidebar.component.html`, `sidebar.component.ts`, `side.module.ts`. Now, on `app.component.html`, I write this `<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>`, but I have an error message -> `'app-sidebar' is not a known element:` Here is the code, if you want -> [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zx5ukw?file=src/app/app.component.html). Thank you su much for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

After you generated your component and copy and paste the code from the sidebar project you should reference the name correctly as `ng-icon-sidebar` not `app-sidebar`.

This should solve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).